# store bitmaps in an array?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to download some images from the server, and I won't save them to the SD card because I want them to be gone when the application finishes.  Therefore I want to store them in an array of bitmaps.  Is this feasible?  My largest image would be about 1000X1086 and there would be about 30-40 of them.

Comment: No... Not feasible...

Comment: Do you literally mean bitmap? What format are the images? What's their file size? What is your overall goal? You provide far too less details to answer your question reasonably.

Comment: i mean literally bitmap format.  Unless there is a better option.  I need those images so I can display them on the screen.  Those "images" are  "cards images" of a "card deck".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  A bitmap is stored in memory as uncompressed bytes.  A 1000x1086 full color bitmap is about 4MB.  Most phones allow an app to use 16-40 MB max, and that includes built in resources.  You're over by a factor of 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Universal Image Loader. You can save the images only in memory and clear it when you exit.

Here are all options for download images.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: That looks interesting, but does it allow you save larger images?

Comment: Yes, this library keeps your images and manages your memory for not throw OutOfMemory. You could try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option... which ain't built in phone memory dependent...
You can save the images in the memory card and delete when the app finishes itself...
This is a really elegant method...